# Refreshing the Jixed Bar div without refreshing the whole page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313203/refreshing-a-div-element-which-has-jsp-code-snippet-inside) showed me how to reload a div using jquery.
In my code I am making a hospital management system where in as soon as the patient arrives into the hospital, the receptionist makes the patient_position=1 in the database.
I am displaying all the patient the have arrived in the hospital to the doctor in the form of a jQuery bar called [JIXED-BAR](https://code.google.com/p/jixedbar/).
This jixed bar retrives values from the database.
I want to continuously refresh this jixed bar so that the doctor is updated about the patient.
My code goes like this.Code for *Reload*

```
    <script langauge="javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
           setInterval(function() {
               jQuery('#demo-bar').load('/status.jsp');
           }, 1000);
        });  
    </script>
```

code for *JixedBar*

```
<div id="demo-bar"></div>
```

Code for *status.jsp*

```
<%javax.naming.InitialContext ctx= new javax.naming.InitialContext();
javax.sql.DataSource ds =(javax.sql.DataSource)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/vi");
java.sql.Connection con = ds.getConnection(); //Assume pool name as jdbc/mydbpool
java.sql.Statement st2 = con.createStatement();
String q2="select * from s";
java.sql.ResultSet rs2 = st2.executeQuery(q2);
while(rs2.next())
{%><ul>
        <li ><a href="tabbedreceptionist.jsp"><%out.println(rs2.getString("h"));%></a></li>
    </ul>
    <span class="jx-separator-left"></span>
    <%}%>
```

Please tell me a way how can i refresh the jixed bar to display the latest information from the database.
Thank you in anticipation.

Comment: well i have figured it out that i was iving the wrong path for the jsp page.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

$(function(){
       setInterval("refreshContent();",1000);
});

function refreshContent()
{
   $.ajax({
         url:'status.jsp';
         success: function(data) {
                $('#demo-bar').html(data)
         }
   });
}

</script>
```